# BackupExec 12 to Bacula questions

Tags: backup

We have a 128 node compute cluster for environmental modeling, with a master/head node which we currently backup with a Windows2003 system running BackupExec 12 and a single HP LTO3 tape drive. We have recently ordered an Overland NEO200s 12 slot library, and are considering migrating off Windows to CentOS 5 for the backup server. The master/head node is RHEL5, with the compute nodes currently being migrated from a mix of RHEL3/4/5 to CentOS5. I'm fairly familiar with RH/Centos, but have no experience with Bacula. We've tentatively settled on Bacula as our cluster vendor recommended it. My questions are: 1) Does Bacula support an Overland NEO200s/LTO3 library? 2) Can Bacula catalog/restore tapes written by BE? and 3) I've head of Amanda, but am even more unfamiliar with it than Bacula. Any assistance would be appreciated

Dave Frandin

Comment: Seems a shame to throw away that Backup Exec environment if it's working reliably. The overland should just plug right in and work with minimal configuration.

Comment: Part of the reason we're investigating going with Bacula is that we're getting hangs in the BE gui when running jobs/creating jobs whenever one or more of the NFS-mounted nodes are off-line. With every node up, RALUS works fine. With any of the 128 nodes off-line, jobs fail to connect and new jobs cannot be created. The failure mode is when you drill down in the fileselection list pulldown, and you click on [root], the BE gui hangs endlessly, until you stop RALUS. We've submitted two tickets to Symantec without a resolution.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Several people have moved off BE to Bacula, some for the reasons you cite, Dave.  Many Bacula users using Overland libraries. I'll check on the specific model you are looking at.

Users have also successfully converted tapes from other systems. Easiest way is to restore the tape with BE then back it up with Bacula, using some tricks we know that allow you to make the Bacula tape have the same date/time stamp as the original backup.  Our CTO is Kern Sibbald, author of Bacula and project manager.

Unlike Amanda, even our Enterprise Edition is GPL so you can use it for free.  Amanda Enterprise requires payment and a proporietary EULA.

Who is the cluster vendor who recommended Bacula?  I would like to write to him to thank him and also to congratulate him on his wise advice :-)

Feel free to contact me:  jack.griffin@baculasystems.com

Comment: Hi! thanks for the info! The cluster vendor is Advanced Clustering Technologies (http://www.advancedclustering.com/). It was one of their techs who set up the headnode. His name escapes me right now.. I'd heard of Bacula previously but was not familiar with it, am currently looking at it on a CentOS5 virtualbox vm, to get somewhat familiar with it. We just recieved the library the other day, so I expect this project will become top priority in the near future... Thanks again for the info...

Dave